# SKlearn pipeline using KNeighborsClassifier

Tags: python, scikit-learn, pipeline, grid-search

I am trying to build a GridSearchCV pipeline in sklearn for using KNeighborsClassifier and SVM. SO far, have tried the following code:

```
from sklearn.model_selection import GridSearchCV
from sklearn.pipeline import Pipeline
from sklearn.neighbors import KNeighborsClassifier
neigh = KNeighborsClassifier(n_neighbors=3)
from sklearn import svm
from sklearn.svm import SVC
clf = SVC(kernel='linear')
pipeline = Pipeline([ ('knn',neigh), ('sVM', clf)]) # Code breaks here
weight_options = ['uniform','distance']
param_knn = {'weights':weight_options}
param_svc = {'kernel':('linear', 'rbf'), 'C':[1,5,10]}
grid = GridSearchCV(pipeline, param_knn, param_svc, cv=5, scoring='accuracy')
```

but am getting the following error:

```
TypeError: All intermediate steps should be transformers and implement fit and transform. 'KNeighborsClassifier(algorithm='auto', leaf_size=30, metric='minkowski',
           metric_params=None, n_jobs=1, n_neighbors=3, p=2,
           weights='uniform')' (type <class 'sklearn.neighbors.classification.KNeighborsClassifier'>) doesn't
```

Can anyone please help me with what am I going wrong, and how to correct it? I think there is something wrong with the last line as well, re params.

Comment: I don't think you can pass two classifiers to `Pipeline`. From the scikit-learn docs: "Intermediate steps of the pipeline must be ‘transforms’, that is, they must implement fit and transform methods. The final estimator only needs to implement fit. The purpose of the pipeline is to assemble several steps that can be cross-validated together while setting different parameters."

Comment: Thanks, but I still didn't get it. Will check for some working examples to understand the concept more. Thanks anyway for your help.

Comment: What @h_s wants to say is, all steps in pipeline (excluding last) must have a transform method, i.e they should modify data in some way or other, but not learn data as a classifier. The `knn` is a classifier. It learns the data to be able to predict later, but doesnt have a `transform` method. Can you tell your use case of using Knn and Svc in same pipeline?

Answer (score 1):

The error clearly says that the  KNeighborsClassifier doesnt have transform method KNN has only fit method where as SVM has fit_transform() method. for the Pipeline we can pass n number of arguments in to it. but all the arguments should have transformer methods in it.Please refer the below link

http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.pipeline.Pipeline.html

Answer (score 0):

The scikit-learn Pipeline steps require to have the `transform()` method. You might want to try the pipeline from imblearn instead.

See for instance here: https://bsolomon1124.github.io/oversamp/